# What is the alternative to <br /> if I want to control the height between lines?

Tags: html, css

In following example:

```
Line1 <br /> Line2
```

I'm using `<br />` to force Line2 to go to next line, but as far as I know there is no cross browser friendly way of setting the height of br. What is an alternative method I could use?

Comment: why did u exclude to wrap the text in several <p /> elements?

Comment: "there is no cross browser friendly way of setting the height of br" That's because `<br>` doesn't have any height. It's just a command to create a new line.

Comment: Use padding, margins or line height.

Comment: are the Line1, Line 2 etc connected? You might be better with a <ul> & <li> tag if there is a semantic link between the Lines

Comment: most answers are correct, it depends on the context of the question

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use differents blocks :

```
<p>Line1</p>
<p>Line2</p>
```

Answer (score 11):

Normally, using `<br />` is old way of breaking a line.
You should use `<p>, <div>` or some block level elements and give them top or bottom margins.

```
p {
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-bottom:5px
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using CSS you can control the `line-height` property of any element.

```css
someElement {
    line-height:12px;
}
```

Now you may simply set this for an element, or use it on the entire HTML to provide uniformity across the document. This is safe, cross-browser compatible and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use css `line-height` property along with `<br/>` tag to control spacing between lines.

```
<style>
.small
{
    line-height:100px;
}
</style>

<p class="small">
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br />
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br />
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br />
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I add a `<div>`, best way for me, with CSS margin. Or,
2. The `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding` & / or `margin` css attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<div>` like this

```html
<div style="height: [put your height here]; display: block;"></div>
```

Seems to work for me, as shown here:

```html
<span>This is the previous line!</span>
<div style="height: 50px; display: block;"></div>
<span>This will be 50 pixels below the previous line.</span>
```

You can even use a span!

```html
<span>This is the previous line!</span>
<span style="height: 50px; display: block;"></span>
<span>This will be 50 pixels below the previous line.</span>
```